# How to reuse AsyncClient fixture

Tags: python, fastapi, httpx

Here is a simple code snippet to demonstrate the problem, it seems that the fixture client is not properly injected into the testing functions.

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from fastapi import FastAPI
import asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient
import pytest

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    print("starting up")
    yield
    print("shutting down")

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get("/hello")
async def hello():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return {"hello": "world"}

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def client():
    async with lifespan(app) as test_app:
        async with AsyncClient(app=test_app, base_url="http://localhost") as client:
            yield client

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_hello(client):
    response = await client.get("/hello")
    assert response.json() == {"hello": "world"}
```

Running pytest will produce the following error message

```
client = <async_generator object client at 0x00000175B3EA1990>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_hello(client):
>       response = await client.get("/hello")
E       AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: You have to use something like `pytest-asyncio` (which it seems you're already using) and mark your fixture as async as well: `@pytest_asyncio.fixture(..)`. What's the reason for not using the built-in TestClient?